# How to Automatically Upload Files to Google Code?

Tags: google-code

I'd like to upload files to my Google Code project automatically, e.g. using a custom NAnt task.

I'm aware of projects such as [ant-googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/ant-googlecode/), [nant-googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/nant-googlecode/), [the Scripted Uploads Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ScriptedUploads), and [this handy Python script](http://support.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/scripts/googlecode_upload.py).  All of them seem out of date for the same reason -- they all use the same upload URL, which is no longer there:

```
https://yourproject.googlecode.com/files
```

(And they all seem to also use an obsolete authentication scheme using network credentials.)

If you know what the new URL is or any source of documentation (I haven't found it on the Google Project Hosting Wiki), please share it.

Comment: Any luck on tracking down the URL? The upload form on Google Code POSTs to the following URL: https://uploads.code.google.com/upload/[project-name]. Unfortunately, the SSL cert on that server is for *.googlecode.com.